# Detect single string fraction (ex: ½ ) and change it to longer string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, fractions

ex: `"32 ½ is not very hot " to x = "info: 32, numerator = 1, denominator = 2"`

Note: it could be `3/9`, but it **cannot** be simplified into `1/3` aka literally get what is in the string.

I need to detect the fractional string in a longer string and expand the information to a more usable form.

`½` has been given to me decoded and is a string with length one.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: predefined dictionary with various vulgar fraction keys. I search each character in the string (str[i] == '½') and if it matches a key,  return the value for that key:  (1/2) which I had to write manually (very short and limited to a few fractions).

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what your inputs/outputs are going to be?  Are you just trying to turn `'½'` into `'1/2'`?  [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) can do that.  `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', '½')`

Comment: @EdZ  What's wrong with that way?  Seems simple and best to me.

Comment: @wim scaling up to cover all possible fractions

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be 19 such forms ([here](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:Decomposition_Type=Fraction:])) and they all start with the name VULGAR FRACTION.

```
import unicodedata

def fraction_finder(s):
    for c in s:
        try:
            name = unicodedata.name(c)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if name.startswith('VULGAR FRACTION'):
            normalized = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', c)
            numerator, _slash, denominator = normalized.partition('⁄')
            yield c, int(numerator), int(denominator)
```

Demo:

```
>>> s = "32 ½ is not very hot "
>>> print(*fraction_finder(s))
('½', 1, 2)
```

Comment: Is it not even possible to do 21/987? There is only 19 vulgar fractions?

Comment: @EdZ  In the current unicode spec, yeah.  I can't say they won't add new ones, though!

Comment: @wim it's actually possible to write any fraction with [subscript and superscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts). Unicode even have U+002F `/` Solidus and U+2044 ⁄ Fraction slash for that purpose. So we can have ²¹/₉₈₇

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc  Yep, but this question is limited to fractions which are "a string with length one" and that seems to rule out the composed forms.

Comment: yeah. There's an infinite number of fractions so it's impossible and impractical to have a lot of codepoints for vulgar fractions

Comment: Off-topic, but [↉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ABaseball_scorekeeping#%E2%86%89?) made me curious.