# Converting irregularly formatted strings containing fractions to floats?

Tags: python, string

I have already looked at other related stackoverflow answers to similar questions ([Convert fraction to float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806278/convert-fraction-to-float)), ASCII encoding, etc, but have been unable to find something that solves the specific string issue I am encountering.

I have a string that contains this value '½', as well as other strings with mixed fractions such as '1 ½'. Passing these values through the fraction library or trying to remove the formatting that is being used results in errors such as

```
ValueError: Invalid literal for Fraction: '½'
```

Trying to use str.split("/") results in no change, passing

```
'½'.str.split("/")
```

returns '½'.

Any tips on how to deal with these strings would be appreciated!

Comment: The fraction that you have given is a single Unicode character which means split will not work. `U+00BD` That is the reason it returns `½` itself.

Comment: Interesting, I looked at ```U+00BD``` and it seems that it is a vulgar fraction? Is there a way of converting this to a numeric value?

Comment: I have created an answer. Please check if that satisfies what you expect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect single string fraction (ex: ½ ) and change it to longer string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49440525/detect-single-string-fraction-ex-%c2%bd-and-change-it-to-longer-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the unicode data module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html

```py
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.numeric(u'½')
0.5
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Haha, yes this is exactly what I found a moment ago. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.numeric(frac)
```

Works great for this situation. For mixed fractions such as `'1 ½'`, it is best to string split and then use `unicodedata` to convert this to numeric.